# Unpack("H*", $data) in PHP behaves differently than PeachPie unpack method

Tags: php, peachpie

```
<?php
$hexStr = "7583B05800000000";
$up = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $hexStr)));
echo $up[1];
?>
```

Output of the above PHP code in the PHP compiler gives

```
0000000058b08375
```

Whereas output of the same code snippet in PeachPie in my Visual Studio 2019 gives different output as below:

```
0000000058EFBFBDEFBFBD75

The above behaviour is part of the c# code using peach pie
```

Comment: this should be posted on [PeachPie issues](https://github.com/peachpiecompiler/peachpie/issues) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: it seems to work fine with the latest PeachPie (1.0.0-preview2), please update and try again

Comment: Looks like it is working now @JakubMíšek Thanks